# AnyLogic NetworkPort cannot connect two different Networks

Tags: anylogic

I created two PoinNodes in different networks in the main Agent. I connected each PointNode to a NetworkPort using a path and then connected the NetworkPorts in the pair with port dropdown. I have a simple process containing of a source, a moveto and a sink. I inject an agent at PointNode1 and the moveto should transport it to Network /GIS node PointNode2. I got the error-message that the agents are not located in the same network, which is obvious but I thought that's what network ports are used for? How can i transport Agents from PointNode1 to PointNode2 using the network paths and the Port?

I dont understand why the moveTo cannot use the network ports to get the agent from one PointNode to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [help](https://anylogic.help/markup/network-port.html#network-port), network ports are supposed to be used for `Transporter` type agents.

Probably easiest if you flag your agent type to be a transporter and it should work:
[image]